# Why with this char "؋" everything I wrote on the right side appear on the left?

Tags: swift, utf-8, char

I want to display on an Xcode project the following char: "؋" which is a currency, and on the right a value.
For example (in dollars): $100.
But with this char everything I wrote on the right side appears on the left, and I don't know why.
Hear how it appears: ؋100.
The sign is on the right, but I wrote "100" with the cursor on the right of the currency symbol.

Comment: The currency is right to leg as Arabian letter. Try to add a space between the symbol and the value.

Comment: It is an Arabic letter, so it is written right to left, and it affect the numbers nearby. There are override characters if you think general rules are broken, else do not mess with internationalization just because you are used in a way.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate, but if you believe there is more to the question, please comment here. In this case, though, the correct solution is not to try to move the currency symbol by hand. You should use a NumberFormatter (or in SwiftUI a FormatStyle) configured for currency in the desired Locale. It will handle the placement.